How to create a new index using reset_index - key error
I've got a dataframe that looks a bit like this although there's more columns.
    Client ID   Fulfilled date
0   309032  2017-05-04
1   309032  2017-06-29
3   331793  2017-07-19
5   319659  2017-05-11
6   321682  2017-05-16

I want to create a flag column is_first_time for first time visitor.
Thought the logic was simple:
def first_time_visitor(self):
    # Create a copy of 'self.df' and sort it by 'Client ID' and 'Fulfilled date'
    temp_df = self.df.copy()
    temp_df.reset_index(inplace=True) #thought this would create a column called index that I could use later.
    temp_df.sort_values(['Client ID', 'Fulfilled date'], inplace=True)
    # Create a new column in 'temp_df' that marks the first occurrence of each client_id
    temp_df['is_first_time'] = ~temp_df['Client ID'].duplicated(keep='first')

    # Convert the boolean values to integers
    temp_df['is_first_time'] = temp_df['is_first_time'].astype(int)
    temp_df = temp_df.sort_values("index")

I then thought I could do something like:
self.df['is_first_time'] = temp_df['is_first_time']

But I get a key error
KeyError: 'index'


Using your Logic: Considering this is an object oriented programming, im assuming that df could be an attribute of the class or could be added as a parameter in the first visitor method.
import pandas as pd

class Table():
    def __init__(self,df):
        self.df=df


def first_time_visitor(self):
# Create a copy of 'self.df' and sort it by 'Client ID' and 'Fulfilled date'
    temp_df = self.df.copy()
    temp_df.reset_index(inplace=True) #thought this would create a column called index that I could use later.
    temp_df.sort_values(['Client ID', 'Fulfilled date'], inplace=True)
    # Create a new column in 'temp_df' that marks the first occurrence of each client_id
    temp_df['is_first_time'] = ~temp_df['Client ID'].duplicated(keep='first')

    # Convert the boolean values to integers
    temp_df['is_first_time'] = temp_df['is_first_time'].astype(int)
    temp_df = temp_df.sort_values("index")

    self.df['is_first_time'] = temp_df['is_first_time']

    return self.df 


data ={'Client ID':[309032, 309032, 331793,319659,321682],'Fulfilled date':['2017-05-04','2017-06-29','2017-07-19','2017-05-11','2017-05-16']}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)

table=Table(df)
table.first_time_visitor()

Output:
Client ID   Fulfilled date  is_first_time
0   309032       2017-05-04        1
1   309032       2017-06-29        0
2   331793       2017-07-19        1
3   319659       2017-05-11        1
4   321682       2017-05-16        1


A possible solution (assuming clients entries are sorted in ascending order, for each client, by Fulfilled date):
df['is_first_time'] = [
    int(df.loc[x, 'ClientID'] not in df.loc[0:(x-1), 'ClientID'].to_list()) 
    for x in range(len(df))]

Output:
   ClientID   Fulfilled  date  is_first_time
0    309032  2017-05-04   NaN              1
1    309032  2017-06-29   NaN              0
2    331793  2017-07-19   NaN              1
3    319659  2017-05-11   NaN              1
4    321682  2017-05-16   NaN              1


You code should work, if the index doesn't already have a name.
reset_index will keep the original name, so you should use:
temp_df.reset_index(inplace=True, names=['index'])

Note however that for your purpose, and if the index doesn't have duplicates, the should be enough:
df['is_first_time'] = ((~df.sort_values(by='Fulfilled date')
                        ['Client ID']
                        .duplicated()).astype(int)
                      )

